# Killing multiple processes that were started from nested threads... C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, nested, kill

I'm new to programming. I have a form application that launches a thread. Form there 4 new threads are launched. Each of these threads performs a series of command line processes like the following:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory ="C:\\BLA\\bin_windows";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            startInfo.FileName = "SomeProcess"
            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
        p.WaitForExit();
```

When the form application is closed it aborts the first thread (not the 4 separate ones).
Now my question is how to force the processes "p" to quit when I close the form??
I tried the following:

```
    foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeProcess"))
    {
        try
        {
            p.Kill();
            p.WaitForExit(); // possibly with a timeout
        }
        catch
        { continue; }
    }
```

However, this approach seems a little brutal to me and does not always work well... Is there a way that I can identify only the processes that Ive launched myself and then terminate them?
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What about having the some kind of global list of all processes you started?

Comment: @dwrd -- that sounds good -- but ive no idea how to go about it... could you explain more? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have very little control of processes you have run. Killing them is one way. If the process is a windowed application (i.e. has a window) you can try sending it a `WM_CLOSE` message which is equivalent of clicking a close button on the window. Again, application must have a window, either visible or hidden and because of that it will not work on every application. Most applications do have windows though even if not visible.

```
const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
if(p != null)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
}
```

To kill/close only processes you have spawned just keep their `Process` objects or at least `p.MainWindowHandle` if you want to use approach I gave you. For that, have a public property of type `ConcurrentBag<Process>` (or `ConcurrentBag<IntPtr>`) in your class. It is already thread safe.

**EDIT**

As someone pointed out you can do this to close process' main window:

```
p.CloseMainWindow()
```

Comment: thanks - since they are command line programs i dont think they have windows?! or? Also, it would be good to only kill what was launched by the form application.

Comment: @timkado It should work on console apps too because they do have windows. To kill only processes you've spawned, keep their `Process` objects or at least `p.MainWindowHandle`

Answer (score 0):

If your program is not supposed to be runed twice a time you could use some kind of process manager on singleton:

```
internal sealed class ProcessManager
{
    private readonly IList<Process> processes;

    #region Singleton

    private static readonly object locker = new object();
    private static volatile ProcessManager instance;

    private ProcessManager()
    {
        processes = new List<Process>();
    }

    public static ProcessManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new ProcessManager();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void AddProcess(Process process)
    {
        lock(processes)
        {
            processes.Add(process);
        }
    }

    public void TerminateAll()
    {
        lock(processes)
        {
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                try
                {
                    p.Kill();
                    p.WaitForExit(); // possibly with a timeout
                }
                catch
                {
                     continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory ="C:\\BLA\\bin_windows";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        startInfo.FileName = "SomeProcess"
        Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
        ProcessManager.Instance.AddProcess(p);
    p.WaitForExit();
```

If you don`t wish static things in your prog (for example, you can have some instances of it), you can use this class, but without singleton and give its single instance to every thread.

Comment: Or you could replace nearly all of that code with `public static ConcurrentBag<Process> processes = new ConcurrentBag<Process>();`

Comment: Heh, didn`t know about ConcurrentBag class :) Good note

Comment: You can get ConcurrentBags for a very reasonable price in many Nevada bars, though after the fifth large JD, you would be better off with a queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the process, there's no need to P/Invoke and send a WM_CLOSE message, just call the [CloseMainWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) method on your Process instance (which will send a WM_CLOSE for you). You can then follow it up with the [Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx) method to release your local view of it.

Keeping track of the processes you've started is fairly easy as well.

```
public static ConcurrentBag<Process> processes = new ConcurrentBag<Process>();
```

Store your processes as you create them.

```
Process process = ... //Create your process
processes.Add(process);
```

And then cycle through and close them.

```
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    if (!process.HasExited)
    {
        process.CloseMainWindow();
        process.Close();
    }
}
```