# How to kill multiple processes

Tags: c#, sql, process, task

I need some help, Within a program I am creating! I have a simple task manager where i can kill a single process! However, i need it so I can kill multiple processes, been stuck a few days and a little unsure how to kill multiple processes. Can anyone give me any advice?

By multiple processes, i dont mean just put more processes in along side firefox, i mean load multiple processes from a listview or sql?

here is my code so far. I was thinking maybe it was possible to save the processes to sql, and then load them in to where fire fox is?

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process pr in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())//GETS PROCESSES
{
  if (pr.ProcessName == "firefox")//KILLS FIREFOX.....REMOVE FIREFOX.....CONNECT SAVED SQL PROCESSES IN HERE MAYBE??
  {
      pr.Kill(); //KILLS THE PROCESSES
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you are asking .... the problem how to get the process name or how to kill many process ?

Comment: duplicate???? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252155/killing-multiple-processes-that-were-started-from-nested-threads-c-sharp

Comment: Hi there, I can kill a single process, "put any process where firefox is" but this isn't efficient for what i want to do. I want to be able to load multiple processes into where firefox is. For example:

On my task manager, all the processes load, i select say around 10 processes to kill! So i save these processes into sql, Is it possible to load these processes so i can kill them all at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();// SQL STUFF
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProcessName FROM ApplicationProcesses", con);
// since you start from SqlDataAdapter I'm continue from there..           
da.Fill(ds, "ProcessNames");
// get the process in the database to a array
string[] preocesArray = ds.Tables["ProcessNames"]
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(row => row.Field<string>("ProcessName"))
        .ToArray();

// kill the process if it is in the list 
var runningProceses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < runningProceses.Length; i++)
{
    if (preocesArray.Contains(runningProceses[i].ProcessName))
    {
        runningProceses[i].Kill(); //KILLS THE PROCESSES
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use LINQ for the second part too:

`List<Process> processes =
                Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => processNamesToKill.Contains(p.ProcessName)).ToList();

            processes.ForEach(p => p.Kill());`

Comment: @ByteBlast I haven't use linq or Foreach becouse it may fail since we are doing kill process in the loop, iterator may not work correctly

Comment: Thought I had it then! Chucks up an error on da.Fill(ds, "ProcessNames");

The error says "The Connection Stringproperty has not been initialized"

Going to double check some code. Any ideas?

Thank you for putting me on the right track though! Much appreciated

Comment: @Damith The connection string is there Connecting. I must be missing something. Thank you for help. I think i need to check some stuff. Im still learning as you can tell :P

Comment: @Damith The one thing i hate about coding, is the simple typo mistakes that can be made! It works beautifully now! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: can you past your connection string as comment? there may be problem we can help you to fix

Comment: @Damith Thanks for your help buddy, i had a simple typo in the connection string! Works a charm! Helped me out so much!